# How can I set a parameter using link_to in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a haml file I have an element such as the following:

```
%th Movie Title
```

that I am trying to turn into a clickable element that will sort the column it is the header for. So far I've worked out that this may look something like the following

```
%th= link_to "Movie Title", "foo"
```

except I need to set a parameter and instead of going to "foo" I want to just reload the current page with the list of movies sorted in the controller (though separate research, my guess is that this can be done via something like:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.find(:all, :order => params[:sort])
end
```

Can someone give me some advice on what I should do about the link_to call? Is anything I've written above way off? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
= link_to 'Movie Title', request.parameters.merge({:sort => "title ASC"})
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed the param name to :sort. Also, for me the merge was unnecessary I guess since I only had one parameter that I was keeping track of.

Comment: Notice that you have access to the `params` method in a view as well as in a controller.